# I tried a lot of different things in order for the program to work. I am trying to print a hollow box with two integers as the length and height

Tags: java

Your task is to read a pair of positive integers, L and H, from the user. Both L and H will be less than 21. Your program then prints out an empty box of asterisks with L horizontal stars and H vertical stars.

The box is empty. For example, if the input data is 6 and 4 then the output should be:

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;

class Unfilled {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("First int: ");
        int L = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Second Int: ");
        int H = keyboard.nextInt();

        if ((L < 21) && (H < 21)) {
            for(int i = 0; i < L; i++){
                System.out.print("*");

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I put the task in the code. I am just confused about how to create that empty box. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: read this 
 https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: @Vhas21 You need another `for` loop inside the current `for` that goes until `H`, then put an `if`-`else` that checks if you should put a `*` or an empty space.  I whipped up a working version really quick so this is definitely a simple way to do it.  I'll let you figure out what the `if` condition should be!

Answer (score 1):

Modify your main method something like following. I haven't tested, but it should give you ideas.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try (Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in)) {

        System.out.println("First int (length): ");
        int L = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Second Int (height): ");
        int H = keyboard.nextInt();

        if ((L > 0 && H > 0) && (L < 21 && H < 21)) {

            for (int j = 0; j < H; j++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < L; i++) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

            return;
        }           
    }

    System.out.println("Bad input. Please enter values between [1-20].");
}
```